# How to cast a nullable DateTime to UTC DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller, nullable, null-coalescing-operator

I'm reading back a DateTime? value from my view. Now I check to see if the `NextUpdate` DateTime? `HasValue` and if so convert that time to `UTC`.

From reading up on this it seems I need to use a `null coalescing operator` but my assignment tells me that System.NUllable does not contain a definition for `ToUniversalTime()` when using that operator.

I've searched on SO for a similar question but no luck on that.

**Question:**

How can I convert a null DateTime value to UTC?

Code:

I'm simply checking if the DateTime? has a value, and if so convert that DateTie to UTC -

```
            if (escalation.NextUpdate.HasValue)
            { 
                escalation.NextUpdate = escalation.NextUpdate ?? escalation.NextUpdate.ToUniversalTime(); 
            }
            else
            {
                escalation.NextUpdate = null;
            }
```

My `NextUpdate` property in the model:

```
    public DateTime? NextUpdate { get; set; }
```

Comment: You mean `escalation.NextUpdate?.ToUniversalTime()`, perhaps?

Comment: change ``escalation.NextUpdate.ToUniversalTime()`` to ``escalation.NextUpdate.Value.ToUniversalTime()``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the above worked :)

Comment: you are checking 2 times for null once inside if and once again in the if block, you just need to check once for null

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code is wrong in more than one way.

The `??` operator returns the *left side* if it is *not null*, otherwise the right side.
Since you already checked that `escalation.NextUpdate.HasValue` is `true`, the left side is not `null` and you assign the same date again (without converting to UTC).

`Nullable<DateTime>` does not declare `ToUniversalTime()`, you need to do that on the value.

So the final code should look like this:

```
if (escalation.NextUpdate.HasValue)
    escalation.NextUpdate = escalation.NextUpdate.Value.ToUniversalTime();
```

or with C#6

```
escalation.NextUpdate = escalation.NextUpdate?.ToUniversalTime();
```

There is no need for the `else` branch as in that case it would be `null` anyway.

Comment: should'nt it be ``escalation.NextUpdate?.Value.ToUniversalTime()`` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I first thought so, too. But suprisingly this works fine.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that is a good question, but ? operator automatically calls the value property

Comment: @EhsanSajjad actually `escalation.NextUpdate?.Value` is not possible, as `?.` already evaluates to the `DateTime` and no longer a `DateTime?` (though the return type of the _whole_ expression is still `DateTime?`)

Comment: Since C#6 is being around for a half of year, I'm wondering if we still need to provide pre C#6 alternatives and specify explicitly the C#6 options?

Comment: @IvanStoev half a year is nothing, i still know plenty of places that are still using VS2008

Comment: @IvanStoev I agree, but the last time I answered in c#6 only, the OP mentioned that he cannot use c#6....but I could change to answer c#6 only first and provide pre-6 answers only if necessary.

Comment: @MikeT That's their problem. VS2015 can target all reasonable NET framework versions, I see no reason not using it.

Comment: @IvanStoev, the answer is always money, CE is viable for home users but licensing is required for commercial use and not every company is willing to ante up for MSDN subscriptions a or annual software updates. remember that in most companies IT is at the bottom of the food chain as a central support not a revenue generator

Comment: @MikeT I know, but again, that's their problem. They might want to stay on C#1, that doesn't mean we should support that here. At least not **by default**.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using c#6 then its very simple

```
escalation.NextUpdate?.ToUniversalTime();
```

this translates as if NextUpdate is not null call ToUniversalTime() else return null

if you can't use c#6 then inline if is probably your best bet

```
escalation.NextUpdate.HasValue ? (DateTime?)escalation.NextUpdate.Value.ToUniversalTime():null;
```

this is basically the same as your full if baring you've missed out the Value property of the nullable and corrects your use of the ?? operator